# PostgreSQL 9.3: Add/Remove QUARTER to/from timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, intervals, postgresql-9.3

I want to add the `QUARTER` to the `TIMESTAMP` in PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

#### My Try:

For adding:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL '01 QUARTER';
```

For remove:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01' - INTERVAL '01 QUARTER';
```

> ```
> ********** Error **********  
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "01 QUARTER"  
> SQL state: 22007  
> Character: 42
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because <strike>`quarter`</strike> is not among supported units for `interval` input. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)

> unit is `microsecond`, `millisecond`, `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `week`,
>   `month`, `year`, `decade`, `century`, `millennium`, or `abbreviations` or plurals of these units;

Use `'3 month'` (or similar) instead:

```
SELECT timestamp '2016-01-01' + interval '3 month';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just wanted to confirm because `SQL Server` have that type of unit in it.